# TypeValue: cannot read property 'properties' of undefined

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, command-prompt

I'm learning JS through an online video tutorial. When I try to type 'npm run dev' into command prompt I get the following error:

[Command Prompt Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76DnD.jpg)

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: make sure you install npm first and then try `npm start` and send me your feedback

Comment: Also, you could share the link to the video or the repository you're using to better understand the problem so we can help you out, if @neginmotalebi's suggestion didn't do it.

Comment: of course; I share it with you as an answer. I'm not sure be helpful but I hope so.

Comment: OP, please consider sharing the error as text instead of solely an image. Being able to copy text is often very valuable for those attempting to help debug your situation, not to mention that image contents can't be searched and found by others who may be having the same issue.

Comment: @negin motalebi
npm start got errors too

Comment: The video tutorial is paid for so I can't share it. But I can share what it is teaching and the contents of the error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'properties' of undefined
    at module.exports (C:\Users\rosta\Documents\JavaScript_Build_Real_Projects_2020\9-forkify\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\config-yargs.js:89:48)
    at C:\Users\rosta\Documents\JavaScript_Build_Real_Projects_2020\9-forkify\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\webpack.js:60:27
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rosta\Documents\JavaScript_Build_Real_Projects_2020\9-forkify\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\webpack.js:515:3)

Comment: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1164:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:993:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rosta\Documents\JavaScript_Build_Real_Projects_2020\9-

Comment: forkify\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:156:2)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! forkify@1.0.0 dev: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the forkify@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rosta\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-22T01_43_25_842Z-debug.log

Comment: Tried 'npm start' and got this error:

C:\Users\rosta\Documents\JavaScript_Build_Real_Projects_2020\9-forkify>npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rosta\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-22T17_07_51_341Z-debug.log

C:\Users\rosta\Documents\JavaScript_Build_Real_Projects_2020\9-forkify>